# Не могу подключиться к ДБ

Tags: php, laravel

Не могу подключиться к БД на сайте. Сайт запущен на OpenServer, БД находится в phpMyAdmin.

Вот конфигурация БД.

```
    'mysql' => [
        'driver' => 'mysql',
        'host' => env('DB_HOST', 'myhost'),
        'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
        'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'name_db'),
        'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'root'),
        'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
        'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
        'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
        'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
        'prefix' => '',
        'strict' => true,
        'engine' => null,
    ],
```

Когда запускаю сервер, то выдает вот такие вот ошибки:

> (2/2) QueryException
>
> SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user
>   'vh231045_root'@'localhost' (using password: YES) (SQL: insert into
>   `online` (`referer`, `useragent`, `page`, `ip`, `time`) values (-,
>   Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML,
>   like Gecko) Chrome/66.0.3359.181 Safari/537.36, https://eazy,
>   127.0.0.1, 1527612272))
>
> in Connection.php (line 647)

В ошибке почему-то другая конфигурация БД, не знаю почему. Как правильно подключаться к БД?

Comment: А что с `.env` ?

Comment: @KostaB. только что изменил там данные на свои все заработало. В этом была проблема

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Измените файл `.env`

```
DB_HOST=localhost
DB_DATABASE=<your-db-name>
DB_USERNAME=<your-user-name>
DB_PASSWORD=<your-password>
```